# Is there a way to create an android application that can be used to change the system font device-wide?

Tags: android, kotlin, fonts, jetpack

I wanted to create an application that can be used to change the font of the device, and I am a newbie android developer. So if anyone could help me out i will be very grateful. Thanks!

I've tried finding the permission to add in the manifest file but couldn't find any permission that lets me change the system font.

Comment: Android does not provide any default API to change the whole system font itself as per security concern.  Modifying system-level settings, including the system font, typically requires elevated permissions, So if you do so without default theming apps, you need root privilege to do so.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it without rooting the phone. @Sanjay

Comment: No, there is no other way, that you can do without rooting!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question sanjay!!